# Pressing dead keys twice

Tags: keyboard, input

I've recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu 11.04, and a difference that bugs me a bit is, when a dead key (such as `^` or `´`) is pressed twice, the behavior differs in the two OS'es.

On Windows, the first press is dead, but the second press gives you two characters. So, for instance, pressing `¨` once nets you nothing, but twice nets you `¨¨`.

On Ubuntu, the first press is also dead, but the second press only nets you one character. So, pressing `¨` once nets you nothing, twice nets you `¨`.

What I'd like to do is make dead keys function as on Windows, that is, pressing them twice nets you the character two times.

I do not wish to make them non-dead, as I then wouldn't be able to write for ü, for instance.

Is such a thing possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I remember this behavior from my Windows days and it always boggled me what the use case could be for wanting two of them, any insight? I don't think there was a single time where I didn't use the backspace after hitting a dead key twice.

Comment: For instance, when writing LaTeX, quoted text is written like ``this''. There's also the smiley ^^.

Comment: I see, Kile autocorrects my " into `` or '' depending on what's needed.

Comment: I just defined my own qq{} and q{} function for quotes. If you use a specific editor, you might be able to program that one ` will output `` or so

Answer (score 1):

You can get similar behavior with the compose key. The compose key can be set under System Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Options -> Compose Key. Now, to type ü, press compose, release compose and then proceed as you would in Windows.

Edit: Misread slightly, you'd need to make the keys dead before doing this, which for me, they were by default.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't possible as far as I know; however if you would change your keyboard-layout to one with `AltGr` deadkeys, you'll still be able to have your deadkeys like `ü`.

How to get those deadkeys is very easy; e.g. `ü` would be `AltGr + Shift + '`.

If you don't have a dedicated `AltGr` key, then the right `Alt` key would be that key.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'd like to do is make dead keys function as on Windows, that is,
>   pressing them twice nets you the character two times.
>
> I do not wish to make them non-dead, as I then wouldn't be able to
>   write for ü, for instance.

I wanted the same thing and failed to find an easy way to have ubuntu behave exactly like windows (dead key, but type it twice when typed twice). The solution that I am now using for myself uses dead keys, but still allows me to type special characters that are not on my keyboard, like `à`.

What I need to do to write such a character is to first press the "compose key".

There are multiple ways to set a compose key, including a nice gui with `gnome-tweak-tool` as proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/70788/606260). But using <kbd>Capslock</kbd> or <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> really messed with my flow.

So I propose [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1220801/606260): Set a combination as your control key. I set it to <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd> and now anything I type immediately after I release these two keys will be combined into one character.

This is done as follows:

1. Set your keyboard layout to not use dead keys
2. Find the available options with `grep "compose:" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`
3. Set your preferred option using something like this command

```bsh
    dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['compose:lwin-altgr']"
```

4. You might have to log out and back in again

Comment: I am facing a very similar issue, only difference is that I did need to type the ` (dead_grave) only once. I don't want it to work for typing composed characters (I need it for develop code). right now I have to type twice to get a single quote. any advice?

Comment: @cesarpachon have you tried all the keyboard layouts that are normally available? E.g. for swiss german, there are like 4 options. I might misunderstand you, but perhaps all you need is a keyboard layout that says "no dead keys"

Comment: I don't want to change the full layout, just customize a single key. I have a spanish keyboard and the dead_grave key needs to be activated with alt gr. in US keyboards it is a direct keystroke. all other keys are ok. I was able to change that behavior with xmodmap but  I need yet to press twice to insert the character. I would like to press it only once for writing code.  like: instead of à  I want just: `hello` (javascript feature for interpolated strings).
Thanks for your suggestion I will search for alternative layouts (I would like to preserve dead_acute for spanish: Canción)

Comment: Hmm, okay. I would advise you to ask a new question then, @cesarpachon. I don't know how, but I'm sure that should be doable with some keybinding mapping